# Should carbon monoxide detectors be installed in rooms containing gas appliances?

Tags: installation, carbon-monoxide, placement

This might be 2 questions so I can separate it into two if needed.

I want to put a CO detector in two places of my home (kitchen and garage).  However, the instructions that came with the CO detector said not to put it in there.

In the kitchen, I have a gas stove.  I also want to put one in the garage because of the water heater.

I was reading the instructions for the CO detector.  It said not to put one in either of these rooms.  It doesn't state any exceptions (water heater/gas stove) so I don't know if it saying not to install it in these rooms is with or without the presence of these appliances.

Should I install detectors in these rooms or not?

Comment: With modern gas appliances, CO isn't really the risk to be concerned about.  They either light or they don't.  If they light, there isn't a problem with incomplete combustion.  If you want to detect a more realistic risk, install a gas detector.  The more likely problem is a gas leak or gas failing to ignite.

Comment: @fixer1234 if the flue is not ventilating properly or the appliance isn't installed correctly then it **will** be a problem.

Comment: @ratchetfreak, an installation problem should be immediately evident.  A gas stove isn't vented (for combustion).  It ignites or it doesn't.  My point was that assuming things have been installed correctly, the risk of a gas leak or unignited gas is much greater than the risk of CO.  So if you're concerned enough to put in a detector/alarm, it makes more sense to make it a gas detector.  However, there are combined gas/CO detectors that aren't much more expensive, so that could be the way to go.

Comment: @Classified, here's a link with guidance, and the logic for it, for CO detector placement: http://www.carbonmonoxidedetectorplacement.com/.

Comment: Just remember why the CO2 sensors are there. They are to protect the occupants from over exposure to CO2. So your best locations are where you spend the most time in your house.

Comment: @fixer1234 -- appliances can go off-spec on combustion (due to clogging of combustion air vents or other remodeling work that influences the air supply), and you can get venting problems after-the-fact [like](http://www.waterheaterrescue.com/FunStuff/horrorpages/inspection-horror-people-vent.html) [this](http://www.waterheaterrescue.com/FunStuff/horrorpages/inspection-horror-rheem-vent.html), too...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, good points.

Comment: @RME - its Carbon Monoxide (CO) we're worried about not Carbon Dioxide (CO2) which is mostly harmless.   
In some states they are now are requirement.  http://www.mass.gov/eopss/agencies/dfs/osfm/pubed/fs-topics/carbon-monoxide-detectors.html

Comment: Keep in mind if using dual smoke/co2, the sensors are installed I believe within 2' at the highest point of a room, e.g.,  vaulted ceilings.

Comment: Current code asks for detectors to be outside of any sleeping areas on any floor.   Generally if a room in a residential house has a door, consider  it a bedroom.  I'm guessing if a detector was in a bedroom, maybe it's already too late? And double check all of this by calling up the local fire marshall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good idea to follow the manufacturer's directions.

**You do not want to install CO detectors near appliances.**

**You want them installed near people.**

A living room or dining room is best.  One for each floor, and near bedrooms.

But not in a garage or in a kitchen with gas appliances.

Also, remember to mount them near or just above the height of the average adult's face - that's 5 or 6 feet off the floor.

Here is a good article about them:

[CO Detector Do's and Don'ts](http://www.sterlinghomeinspections.com/sterling-home-inspection-blog/2013/12/10/carbon-monoxide-detector-placement-dos-and-donts)

In a nutshell, it says:

*In order to ensure that your home has maximum protection, it's important to have a CO detector on every floor. Carbon monoxide detectors can get the best reading of your home's air when they are placed five feet from the ground. Near every sleeping area.*

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't want to install CO detectors in the kitchen or garage, or too close to any gas-burning appliance.

You want CO detectors if you have gas appliances, but (somewhat ironically) you don't want to place the detectors close to those appliances. This is to reduce the number of false positives you get from the detector.

CO detectors should be placed on each level of the house, in each bedroom or just outside the doors if two or more bedrooms are close to each other.

Comment: You can actually get combination CO2 and Smoke Detectors now. If you want swap out your old smoke detectors.